# How to compare multiple fields in Elm?

Tags: comparison, elm

I'm currently writing a web-based vocabulary trainer in Elm. This requires sorting a list of words by a custom comparator.

The type I want to sort is:

```
type alias Word =
  { id: Int
  , sourceWord: String
  , targetWord: String
  , numTries: Int
  , numCorrect: Int
  , createdAt: Maybe Date    -- might be empty, therefore wrapped in Maybe 
  , lastAskedAt: Maybe Date  -- might be empty, therefore wrapped in Maybe
  }
```

type alias WordList = List (Word)

My rules for comparison are (in descending order of importance):

- number of correct guesses (asc)
- number overall guesses (desc)
- when word was last asked (asc)
- when word was added (desc)

The best approach I could come up with is this:

```
compareWords: Word -> Word -> Basics.Order
compareWords w1 w2 = 
  let
      dateToComparable d = Date.Format.format "%Y-%m-%d" d 
      orderNumCorrect = compare w1.numCorrect w2.numCorrect 
      orderNumTries = compare w2.numTries w1.numTries -- switch ordering to sort descending
      orderLastAskedAt = case (w1.lastAskedAt, w2.lastAskedAt) of
        (Just a1, Just a2) -> compare (dateToComparable a1) (dateToComparable a2)
        (Nothing, Just _)  -> Basics.LT
        (Just _,  Nothing) -> Basics.GT
        (Nothing, Nothing) -> Basics.EQ 
      orderCreatedAt = case (w2.createdAt, w1.createdAt) of -- switch ordering to sort descending
        (Just a1, Just a2) -> compare (dateToComparable a1) (dateToComparable a2)
        (Nothing, Just _)  -> Basics.LT
        (Just _,  Nothing) -> Basics.GT
        (Nothing, Nothing) -> Basics.EQ 
   in
      case orderNumCorrect of
        Basics.EQ -> case orderNumTries of
          Basics.EQ -> case orderLastAskedAt of
            Basics.EQ -> orderCreatedAt
            _ -> orderLastAskedAt
          _ -> orderNumTries 
        _ -> orderNumCorrect
```

which I don't like for a number of reasons:

- it's ugly as hell
- it requires me to use `Date.Format.format` (from mgold/elm-date-format) to compare Date values (since Date apparently is not `comparable`)

Is there a more elegant / Elm-ish way to achieve what I want?

**Update + solution**

As @"Zimm i48" suggested in their most excellent answer, here's a much shorter version that uses the [elm-ordering package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/matthewsj/elm-ordering/1.1.0/Ordering):

```
dateToComparable : Maybe Date -> Time
dateToComparable =
    Maybe.map Date.toTime >> Maybe.withDefault 0 

compareWords : Ordering Word
compareWords =
    Ordering.byField .numCorrect
        |> Ordering.breakTiesWith (Ordering.byField (.numTries >> negate))
        |> Ordering.breakTiesWith (Ordering.byField (.lastAskedAt >> dateToComparable))
        |> Ordering.breakTiesWith
            (Ordering.byField (.createdAt >> dateToComparable >> negate))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more Elm-ish way of doing this kind of things is compositionally, thanks to the `|>` operator.
The [elm-ordering](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/matthewsj/elm-ordering/1.1.0/Ordering) library provides the primitives that you need to do this kind of things, especially the `Ordering.byField` and `Ordering.breakTiesWith` functions.

As for the dates, my advice would be to use `Date.toTime` (the resulting values are comparable).

Bonus: full implementation of your ordering function available for testing here: https://runelm.io/c/xoz. You can see it's much simpler and more readable than yours...

Comment: Excellent! I've added the relevant part of your solution to my question to avoid a dependency on runelm.io - or would you prefer to update your answer text accordingly?